# Como fazer debug com XFS

Tags: c++-builder

Estou trabalhando com `CEN/XFS ATM`. Peguei um código pronto, e precisarei fazer reparos nele. A linguagem é em `C++ Builder`.

Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de debugar o código usando uma impressora serial.  Estou usando o *Wosa* para fazer alguns testes, mas não consegui debugar com ele.

Comment: Não tem um mock ou emulador da impressora?

Comment: Na verdade eu tenho uma impressora térmica para testar aqui com o código XFS. Só que eu queria dar debug para ir conhecendo melhor o código, mas não estou conseguindo. À princípio atachei o wosa ao código que tenho aqui do XFS, em run parameters do c++ builder. Me foi passado que dava para fazer debug dessa forma, mas não consegui.